# Filtering an Array of Sheets on three criteria with output being the URL link to the filtered sheets

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I am creating two lists of links on my opening sheet (9060DASH) in Google Sheets. It looks like this:

[image: Picture of the 9060DASH sheet]

One list is links to all sheets that are not hidden (Active) and one to all that are hidden. Each item must meet two other criteria to be included:

1. The sheet name must not include the numbers "9060."
2. The cell GH3 in the sheet must contain "Protected."

I have a functioning script, but it is loading too slowly. Here is a sample to show how it loads during onOpen(). How can I do this more efficiently? Can it be done better using "push"? Here is the script:

```
function populateSheetList() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("9060DASH").activate();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ss.getRange('9060DASH!D4:E100').clear();
      var counter = 4;
      var sheetName = "";
      var cellID= "";
      var richValue = "";
      var sheetURL = ss.getUrl();
      var sheetLink = ""
      var mySheet = "";
      var shouldNotContain = '9060'; //array code from stackover to build array without 9060 sheets
      var sheetNames = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().map(s => s.getName());
      var filtered = sheetNames.filter(x => !x.toLowerCase().match(shouldNotContain.toLowerCase()));
     /** CREATES ACTIVE SHEETS LIST */
      for(var i =0;i<filtered.length;i++){
        cellID = '9060DASH!D'+counter;
        sheetName = filtered[i]; 
        mySheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
        sheetLink = sheetURL+'#gid='+ mySheet.getSheetId();
        if(mySheet.isSheetHidden() == false){
          if(ss.getRange(sheetName+"!GH3").getValue() == "Protected"){
            richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
            .setText(sheetName)
            .setLinkUrl(sheetLink)
            .build();
            ss.getRange(cellID).setRichTextValue(richValue);
            counter = counter+1;
          }
        }
      }
     /** GATHERING HIDDEN SHEETS */
      var counter = 4;
      for(var i =0;i<filtered.length;i++){
        cellID = '9060DASH!E'+counter;
        sheetName = filtered[i]; 
        mySheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
        sheetLink = sheetURL+'#gid='+ mySheet.getSheetId();
        if(mySheet.isSheetHidden() == true){
          if(ss.getRange(sheetName+"!GH3").getValue() == "Protected"){
            richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
            .setText(sheetName)
            .setLinkUrl(sheetLink)
            .build();
            ss.getRange(cellID).setRichTextValue(richValue);
            counter = counter+1;
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code? It would be nice if you can share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: It writes out the links one by one, with a long pause between each. I know there is a better way to build and put out the array, but I don't know how to handle the three criteria. Do we have the capacity to add video to illustrate? If I make the example small, it won't show the slowness. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, if someone can help with just one of the two lists--the one for the active sheets (the segment labeled * CREATES ACTIVE SHEET LIST *), I can figure out the hidden one. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet so the community can check the behavior?

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel. I've created a copy and stripped out all but the elements that build the dashboard, so you can see how it operates as OnOpen() runs. That script calls the one that runs the code I posted above. My interest is in how to speed up the populating of the two lists. Here's a link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10zAk2sBE0cs4lac4mJDesiAv-XPL6SZe_SROB4fjVz8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reduced the time to load the dashboard by rearranging a number of things and by getting a final array before writing anything out to the dash. I reformatted the cells and sorted the records before the evaluation loops began. I added more status messages, to keep users engaged while the background work was going on. I put the criteria of separating active from hidden sheets last and, depending on which, wrote the values to two different arrays (actvSheets and hidnSheets). Then I processed each array out to the dashboard. I did this in for loops. I suspect I could save even more time to write them out as one command from each array, but I have not been able to figure out how to write out in vertical form. Here is the code. Any refinements are welcome!

```
    /**
     * =================
     * populateSheetList
     * =================
     * This function builds the available sheets in the
     * 9060DASH sheet--containing all with the Protected
     * status.
     */
      function populateSheetListNEW() {
        msgDash("Clearing sheet list . . . ")
        // SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("9060DASH").activate();
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        ss.getRange('9060DASH!D4:E100')
            .clear()
            .setFontSize(14)
            .setHorizontalAlignment('left')
            .sort({column: 4, ascending: true})
        msgDash("Evaluating sheets . . . ")
var counter = 4;
        var sheetName = "";
        var cellID= "";
        var richValue = "";
        var sheetURL = ss.getUrl();
        var sheetLink = ""
        var mySheet = "";
        var actvSheets = [];
        var hidnSheets = [];
        msgDash("Eliminating administrative sheets . . . ")
        var shouldNotContain = '9060'; //array code from stackover to build array without 9060 sheets
        var sheetNames = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().map(s => s.getName());
        var filtered = sheetNames.filter(x => !x.toLowerCase().match(shouldNotContain.toLowerCase()));
        var sortFilt = filtered.sort();
        /** CREATES SHEET ARRAYS */
        msgDash("Gathering census worksheets . . . ")
        for(var i =0;i<sortFilt.length;i++){
            sheetName = sortFilt[i]; 
            mySheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
            if(ss.getRange(sheetName+"!GH3").getValue() == "Protected"){
              if(mySheet.isSheetHidden() == false){
                    actvSheets.push(sheetName);
                } else {
                    hidnSheets.push(sheetName);              
                }
            }
        }
        msgDash("Gathering active sheets . . . ")
        /** WRITING DATA FROM ACTVSHEETS ARRAY */
        for(var j = 0; j < actvSheets.length; j++){
          sheetName = actvSheets[j];
          mySheet = ss.getSheetByName(actvSheets[j]);
          sheetLink = sheetURL+'#gid='+ mySheet.getSheetId();
          richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
          .setText(sheetName)
          .setLinkUrl(sheetLink)
          .build();
          cellID = '9060DASH!D' + counter;
          counter = counter+1;
          ss.getRange(cellID).setRichTextValue(richValue);
        }
          msgDash("Gathering hidden sheets . . . ");
        /** WRITING DATA FROM HDDNSHEETS ARRAY */
        counter = 4;
        for(var k = 0;  k< hidnSheets.length; k++){
            sheetName = hidnSheets[k];
            mySheet = ss.getSheetByName(hidnSheets[k]);
            sheetLink = sheetURL+'#gid='+ mySheet.getSheetId();
            richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
              .setText(sheetName)
              .setLinkUrl(sheetLink)
              .build();
            cellID = '9060DASH!E' + counter;
            counter = counter+1;
            ss.getRange(cellID).setRichTextValue(richValue);
        }
        msgDash('Dashboard ready. Enjoy your census work!');
        ss.getRange('9060DASH!D2').setValue("For hidden sheets, respond to 'Unhide' instruction. Click Refresh button to rebuild list.");
        Utilities.sleep(20);
        msgDash(''); //clears messages
      }
```